# stopping an AVPlayer in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, avplayer

My Audio Streaming App which has a single **Play / Pause** Button and works fine. However I have little problem while using the `player.pause()` property. Sometimes the stream does not continue after pressing play Button and especially (less often) it happens when application comes to foreground after being sent to background ( for example user opened another music app, now he wants to resume my app and wants to continue again). User may have to kill and restart the app  in order to start the player (audio stream).

In short, Can I use any property such as *`player.stop()`* to make a full stop to the steaming link and resume after with *`player.play()`*

This is what I tries as well, but same problem,:

```
func playPause() {
    if  (player.rate == 1.0) {
        player.rate = 0.0
        self.titleLabel.text = "Paused"

    }
    else {
        player.play()
        self.titleLabel.text = "Now Playing Live!"
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: this was just an experiment, yet still works without any problem. Originally I was using `player.pause()`. Problem exists in both ways

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this and it seems to give no problems at all:

```
 @IBAction func playPauseAction(sender: UIButton) {
      if audioPlayer.rate > 0.0 {
          audioPlayer.pause()
      } else {
          audioPlayer.play()
      }
 }
```